Search Request Random Latency
I was successfully using Meilisearch 1.2.0 to 1.3.3  in a Laravel 9 dev project on Windows 10. About a week ago I had to reinstall Windows and WAMP. After the reinstallation I noticed it now took more than 60 seconds (instead of about 5 seconds) to start the Meilisearch engine (the executable) in a cli window and some search requests by my web application now take between 12 to 30 seconds (instead of 1 second before the reinstallations) to show the results. Since I hadn't changed anything in the code and I'm developing locally, I have no clue why there's this huge delay now.
I tested my code and the delay is clearly coming directly from index searches in my code like these:
    $client = new Client(Search::$url, Search::$key);
    $index = $client->index('releases');
    $releases = $index->search('',
     $searchParams = [
      'filter' => [
        'comp_only = 0',
        'name = "'.$name.'"', 
        'system = "'.$system.'"' 
      ],
      'limit' => 500
     ])->getHits();

I updated Meilisearch from 1.3.3 to 1.11 and completely rebuilt the search indexes but no luck. The results are totally fine but take 12 to 30 seconds instead of 1 second. There is no pattern: The exact same search request takes 1 second one time and another time 15 seconds for the same request. Any hints where I could look to investigate further? Thanks.

This is a question best directed at the meilisearch people, and if you check that tag there are only 20 people watching the tag in the whole of SO. If you are paying for  the service, then contact support. Otherwise check their github issues. Aside from that, you can always downgrade to the version that wasn't problematic.

I think it's a bit weird to suggest a close just because there are only a few people watching a tag. There might still be a chance for help and that's the spirit of SO. Regarding my question: There is no "version that wasn't problematic". The issue is explained in my post.

The close and the comment are unrelated. From an SO perspective I don't think that this question is answerable as there is nothing reproducible in the question that would allow us to provide a definite answer. From the perspective of "hey meilisearch is doing something weird since 1.3" you're far more likely to get useful information from posting where more than 20 people are looking at it. You're welcome to post only here and wait, but it would be more productive to also file an issue on their repo.

A question can be answerable while not being reproducible, because there might be someone who ran into this (or similar) issues in the past -- or at least could give a hint how to investigate further. I've worked as a Scrum Master many years and we've investigated many issues which could be titled as rather mysterious and could not be reproduced. The explanation was almost always in the environment. I've already posted at their discord without any response yet. Their Github would've been the next try.
